# How do I set the rel attribute of a HyperLink widget?

Tags: gwt

```
@UiField Hyperlink historyLink;
this.historyLink.getElement().setAttribute("rel", "nofollow");
```

This sets the rel attribute of the containing div.

```
<div class="gwt-Hyperlink" rel="nofollow"><a href="#!h:home">history</a></div>
```

How do I get at the `a` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use an `InlineHyperlink` instead (if you don't want the `div` wrapper at all), but actually I don't understand the use of `rel=nofollow` on a link with a *#hash*-only href: if that's for Google AJAX crawling, can't you simply avoid outputting the link in the HTML snapshot you send in response to an `_escaped_fragment_` request?

Comment: InlineHyperlink appears to be better then using Hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `a` element this way

```
Element a = historyLink.getElement().getFirstChildElement();
```